# Why does the function 'CGAL::draw' draw a black triangle instead of a polygon in the latest version of CGAL?

Tags: c++, qt5, visualization, cgal

I've upgraded my CGAL installation to the latest version (5.4.1) and I can't use the function `CGAL::draw` anymore - it draws a black triangle instead of everything I need. It's not a problem in my code - even standard examples from the CGAL distribution behave this way. The script below unpacks the CGAL tar-file, then builds and runs the `draw_polygon` example from this tar-file.

```
#!/bin/bash

VERSION=CGAL-5.4.1

tar xJvf ${VERSION}.tar.xz && cd ${VERSION}

mkdir -p build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DWITH_examples=ON ..
make

cd examples/Polygon
make draw_polygon
./draw_polygon&
```

The result is below:

[image: CGAL-draw-result]

If to set the `VERSION` variable in the script above to the value `CGAL-5.2.4` - then the drawing will be correct. What's the problem here?

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- Compiler: g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0

**UPDATE**. I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/6754) on the CGAL bug tracker.

Comment: Works for me with 5.4.1 and master branch. Did you try CGAL 5.3? Any output? You should open an issue on github.

Comment: @sloriot - I tried with 5.3.2 - the same black triangle

Comment: Maybe a problem with OpenGL shaders. There have been some changes in 2021 about compatibility shader mode, this is maybe related. I confirm the basic viewers work for me for CGAL 5.4.

Comment: @gdamiand - I can try to debug this issue, but I don't know how. Could you please advice?

Comment: @gdamiand - as for OpenGL shaders - please see my another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68916854/cgal-5-3-example-program-to-draw-a-triangulation-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.

The issue here is that starting from the version 5.3 the CGAL library Qt5-based visualization subsystem doesn't support old graphics hardware - at least on Linux machines (no idea about Windows or Mac worlds).

It looks like the OpenGL implementation on Linux (called Mesa) checks the graphics hardware in run time and creates graphics context, corresponding to this hardware. So, for the CGAL visualization to work correctly this context must be at least OpenGL 3.2, and corresponding shading language must be at least GLSL 1.50.

For more information about these versions etc. please see [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#OpenGL_and_GLSL_versions).